# IBM Worklight 6.0 - QR Code does not work

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, qr-code, worklight-mbs

I am trying to open hybrid app in my iphone, so the best option for me is scan in a QR code that I can save time to input long URL. But what makes me so upset is that the icon fails to open in a new pop-up window, accordingly, I can't scan it.

I am not sure if the the IE or chrome safety option causing that, or it's Dojo bug.

This is QR code icon that I can't open:

[image]

Comment: Code speaks louder than words. Can you post some code of what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Following the below steps, I havel successfully used the QR code from the Worklight Console's MBS preview page to preview the environment's web resources in the device's mobile browser:

1. **Pre-requisite:** I have installed on my iPhone 5s the following app: [QR Reader for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/qr-reader-for-iphone/id368494609) (you can install any other QR reader app you'd like)
2. Created a new project and application
3. Added the iPhone environment
4. Built and deployed the app
5. Previewed the environment in Worklight Console
6. **Must:** Edited the IP/Hostname field of the QR code:

   [image]
7. Scanned the QR code