# IBM Worklight - Unable to fix tabbar to the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develop a simple application that has a header and a footer (tab bar) which consist of two labels.

**Html:**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="Img1">
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" fixed="bottom">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-right-icon.png" data-dojo-props="transition:'flip',dir:'-1',moveTo:Home">Label</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I tried this, the tab bar still appears at the top of the screen.
How can i fix that at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Is this a web app or native app? If native, you should post your xml layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `TabBar` widget inside a `scrollableView` rather than a `View`.

- Example code: [Fixed Header and TabBar in a Worklight-based Dojo app](http://pastebin.com/sppaaVu0)
- [Documentation reference](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/TabBar.html)

HowTo:

1. Create a new Worklight 6.1.0 project and application and choose to add to it the Dojo Mobile framework via the wizard. Add an environment to test in. [Read this training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf).
2. Using the Rich Page Editor, [drag from the Dojo Palette](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/cdojolibprjsetupwl.html) view a `Heading` widget and a `TabBar` widget into the auto-generated `scrollableView` `div` in the HTML file.

   - You can of course add icons...
   - I've also set `fixed="top"` for the Header so it'll be fixed as well.
3. Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.
4. Because I don't have an Android device, I also added the iPhone environment and loaded the app web resources in my device using the [MBS QR code feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342238/ibm-worklight-6-0-qr-code-does-not-work).

   In both iPhone and Worklight Console preview I was able to see and scroll the app contents while the Header and TabBar are fixed at the top and bottom respectively.

[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0J6t.png)
[image]

Comment: When i tried this with Scrollable view navigations between the views isn't working. Any help regarding that.Take a look of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907901/navigation-between-view-not-working-dojo-worklight-application

Comment: But this question is about FIXED TABBAR; If your TABBAR is now FIXED, this specific question is answered. Please mark as Answered. I will look at the other question.

Comment: I have replied to the other question.