# IBM Worklight - Unable to navigate between views

Tags: android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to develop a simple app that consist of multiple scrollable views, but the navigation between views like from "Home" view to "view1" is not working. Unable find out the reason of that...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="Home">
        <div class="wraper" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Container">
        <img src="images/Shelter1.png" alt="some_text">
        </div>
        <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" fixed="bottom">
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-right-icon.png" data-dojo-props="moveTo:view1">Label</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view1">
    <div class="wraper" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Container">
        <img src="images/Shelter2.png" alt="View">
        </div>
        <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" fixed="bottom">
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-left-icon.png" data-dojo-props="transition:'flip',dir:'-1',moveTo:Home">Previous</li>
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-right-icon.png" data-dojo-props="transition:'flip',dir:'1',moveTo:view2">Next</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view2"></div>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the ID in your `moveTo`. For example:

```
<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-right-icon.png" data-dojo-props="moveTo:view1">Label</li>
```

Should become:

```
<li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" icon="images/Arrow-turn-right-icon.png" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'view1'">Label</li>
```

That way it will work, I tested it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/mL65C/) (I used image placeholders). The best way to know if you need quotes is by checking the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/mobile/TabBarButton). If you look at the `moveTo` property, you will notice that is has an [S] icon in front of it, which means it's a String (and Strings do need quotes).

Comment: Is the usage of *data-dojo-props* really needed here? in my take on it it wasn't required.

Comment: You can replace the `data-dojo-props` with normal HTML attributes. However, many people complain about it not being valid HTML, while using `data-*` attributes is HTML5 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The below example code is built on top of the one [provided to you in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897643/ibm-worklight-unable-to-fix-tabbar-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen); This time around `view`s are added inside the `scrollableView` and you move between them using the `moveTo` attribute, as well as using the `selected` attribute to pick a default view to display inside the `scrollableView`.

**Example code:** http://pastebin.com/SD0SU3wV

**Documentation:**

- [dojox/app/View](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/app/View.html)
- [dojox/app/scrollableView](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.html)
- [dojox/app/TabBar](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/TabBar.html)
- [dojox/app/TabBarButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/TabBarButton.html)

**Edit:** Dimitri's answer pinpoints to your exact error, mine simplifies the example a bit...
I'd go with his. :-)